# map alt+delete in git-bash inputrc

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, git-bash

Does anyone know how to bind key combinations with <kbd>Alt</kbd> in inputrc in git-bash?

I want to map a key combination <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd> to `kill-word`, but when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd> to see what characters it represents, it simply shows `^[`, which is wrong.

I know that in order to bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> to something I can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, which will type `^[[1;5D` and then replace `^[` with `\e` and finally write add this line to `.inputrc`:

```
"\e[1;5D": forward-word
```

But this method doesn't work for me with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>(literally anything)</kbd>.

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/613146/412250) works on Ubuntu, but `stty raw` doesn't work in `git-bash` apparently.